# JQuery using $.get is not executing any success actions

Tags: jquery, get

I've written a JQuery function using a $.get to get some data, and i can see form the dev tools in the browser that it's working and there is data being retrieved.

However, when i try to use the data in the function, it just doesn't execute at all. At first i tried putting the results in Div using it's ID, but that didn't work (see the commented out code)... so then i tried just spitting the data out into the console to validate i could access the 'data', to no luck. And finally i tried just writing a generic console message, but even that won't execute.

Here is the function...

```
function refreshChat(){

    name = '<?php echo $name; ?>';
    mob = '<?php echo $mob; ?>';
    activefriendmob = '<?php echo $activefriendmob; ?>';
    activefriendname = '<?php echo $activefriendname; ?>';

    $.get( "/getallmsgs.php?mob1=" + mob + "&mob2=" + activefriendmob + "&name=" + name + "&activefriendname=" + activefriendname, function( data ) {
        // $('#chat-content').html(data);
        console.log('What is going on??');
    }); 

    $('.outer-chatbox').animate({ scrollTop: $('.outer-chatbox').get(0).scrollHeight}, 2000);
    setTimeout(refreshChat, 2000);

}
```

Any suggestions would be great?

Comment: Http transport is only the part of success. It can fail to parse json, for example. Add an error callback and set a breakpoint here, or print error to console.

Comment: Thanks Tommi, the data returned is html so no need to parse JSON etc. How would I print the error to the console? (especially if it doesn't seem to be executing anything) :-(

Comment: Also, it's out of topic, but it looks like you send to server literally parts of php code. This means you run it on server with `eval`. This is totally insecure.

Comment: As I said, add error callback. `$.get(longurl, function(data) { /*success*/ }).fail(function() { console.error(arguments); });`

Comment: Perfect - that worked a treat. You were right, parse error. I'll have a search around for a solution. Feel free to post this as an answer, and i'll mark it as accepted (as you found the issue).

Comment: Done. If you send html from server and get parse error, you probably have misleading `Content-Type` header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Http transport is only the part of success. It can fail to parse json, for example. Add an error callback and set a breakpoint here, or print an error to the console. Something like this:

```
$.get(longurl, function(data) { 
    /*success callback here */ 
}).fail(function() { 
    console.error(arguments); 
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped identify it as a parseerror. I simply added the dataType of html to the $.get function.... and bob's your uncle, fanny's your aunt!!